# Drush pm-disable needs a higher bootstrap level to run

Tags: drush

I keep having this periodic issue with the pm-disable (amongst other) commands in Drush. I have kicked the tires on configuring Drush -- I have the datbase connect set to 127.0.0.1, have php.ini in the ~/.drush dir, using MAMP PHP -- same results.

drush status indicates that it connects without issue. My all directory has user and group level read and write, my site directory has read level on user and group (no write). Do I need to enable different chmod settings in my homesite dir or what am I missing?

This is the pm-disable output when it fails.

```
The drush command 'dis views' could not be executed.                                                                                                      [error]
Drush was not able to start (bootstrap) the Drupal database.                                                                                              [error]
Hint: This may occur when Drush is trying to:
 * bootstrap a site that has not been installed or does not have a configured database. In this case you can select another site with a working database
setup by specifying the URI to use with the --uri parameter on the command line. See `drush topic docs-aliases` for details.
 * connect the database through a socket. The socket file may be wrong or the php-cli may have no access to it in a jailed shell. See
http://drupal.org/node/1428638 for details.

Drush was attempting to connect to: 
 Drupal version         :  7.31                                                                        
 Site URI               :  http://mywellbeing.local                                                    
 Database driver        :  mysql                                                                       
 Database hostname      :  127.0.0.1                                                                   
 Database port          :  8889                                                                        
 Database username      :  mydrupalsite                                                                 
 Database name          :  mydrupalsite                                                                
 PHP executable         :  /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.14/bin/php                                
 PHP configuration      :  /Users/cameronkilgorew/.drush/php.ini /Users/cameronkilgorew/.drush/php.ini 
 PHP OS                 :  Darwin                                                                      
 Drush version          :  7.0-dev                                                                     
 Drush temp directory   :  /tmp                                                                        
 Drush configuration    :                                                                              
 Drush alias files      :                                                                              
 Drupal root            :  /Users/cameronkilgorew/mydrupalsite/repo                                      
 Site path              :  sites/mydrupalsite.local
```

Comment: does `drush sqlc` work?

Comment: `drush sqlc` does work as intended.

Comment: I just noticed you're using drush 7.0-dev on php 5.5.14. Do you have php5-json package? Did you follow the extra instructions on https://github.com/drush-ops/drush related to MAMP?

Comment: It looks like I overlooked configuring the mysql socket. That appears to fix the issue.

Comment: Also, do you ever get a message inside the browser about the database having gone away or any other kind periodic database instability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using drush 7.0-dev on php 5.5.14.

- Do you have php5-json package? That is required for php 5.5.
- Did you follow the extra instructions on github.com/drush-ops/drush related to MAMP? There's one about socket that seems relevant

Answer (score 0):

From my experience this is when you're not running the drush commands from the root of the drupal install.  I tend to get this error when I'm running Vagrant and I forget to `vagrant ssh` into my VM before I start trying to run drush commands.

Comment: That was my initial thought as well -- but even in root and siteroot I get the same error. It doesn't stop me from using Drush for the most part, but when I eventually want to set up aliases and use contrib commands to build subthemes, its going to be a blocker.